# Решено - Рефакторинг ( 2 SQL и логика)

Tags: php, mysql, логика, рефакторинг

Логика: вывести ряд видеороликов (не больше 4х),  первым по списку будут видео согласно значению переменной `$_GET["a"]` (которая соответствует`local_link` в таблице video), остальные по дате добавления (`order by desc`). Текущая ( рабочая, но не "комильфо") реализация такова:

```
    <?php 
    $count_video =0;
    $sql_video='SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE (`local_link`="'.$_GET["a"].'") ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4';
    if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_video)) {
            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
                $index_file = new Video_preview; $index_file->Replase_data("tpl/video_preview.tpl",$row['part_link'],$row['alt'],$row['title'],$row['img_link']);
                $count_video++;
                }
            mysqli_free_result($result);
            }
    if ($count_video < 5) {
                $limit = 4 - $count_video;
                $sql_video='SELECT * FROM `video` WHERE (`local_link`!="'.$_GET["a"].'") ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT '.$limit ;
                if ($result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql_video)) {
                    while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ){ 
                        $index_file = new Video_preview; $index_file->Replase_data("tpl/video_preview.tpl",$row['part_link'],$row['alt'],$row['title'],$row['img_link']);
                }
            }
        }
        ?>
```

Клич помощи: любые преложения по сокращению кода. Возможно ли объединить два запроса в один? Существует ли паттерн для работы с такими условиями?
Мне достаточно будет указать направление "куда копать".

*P.S. Код упрощён, переменная $_GET  проверяется на наличии инъекций отдельно.*

Comment: Если вы уберете с запроса `order by` запрос будет выполнятся быстрее. Сортировку мне кажеться будет уместней делать с `php`. А первые 4 столбца можно вывести с помощью запроса типа: `Select top 4 from table`.

Comment: @ШыназАлиш , не много не соглашусь, пусть я и oldschool -ник, логика построена так что SQL запрос уже отдаёт массив нужных мне данных в правильной последовательности. Тут более критично - что идёт два запроса, а не один. Убрав order by ,  мне придёться вытягивать всю таблицу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Одним запросом:

```sql
SELECT * FROM `video` 
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN `local_link`= '$_GET["a"]' THEN 0 ELSE 1 end, id desc limit 4
```

[CASE в ORDER BY](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_case_order_by_clause.html)

Answer (score 0):

Текущая версия, не считая стилистики написания кода, очень даже "комильфо".

Каждый запрос отвечает за свою задачу.

Можно конечно объединить два запроса в один, но нецелесообразно, т.к. не будут работать индексы БД.